# How do I get rid of this border on generic input?

Tags: html, css, input, searchbar

[image: Border around the searchbar]

I have been trying to remove this border that is on the default input in html. I have tried removing border, padding, making border transparent, ect but I cannot seem to change it. How can I remove it?

Comment: can you provide a code

Comment: ```<input id="main" class="search"></search>```

Comment: ```#main{
  padding: none;
  border: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 220px;
}```

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS as an edit in your initial post but make sure it's correct first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the border that appears when the input is focused :

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

border:0 should do the trick, but if it isn't working try disabling the outline by using outline:none

Or you can disable the appearance e.g -webkit-appearance:none

Also try applying a transparent color to the border, border-color:transparent.

One of this should do the trick.